# F5 backup whole bigIP configuration and save UCS

Tags: load-balancing, load-balancer, f5, backups

I'm trying to export my current F5 bigIP configuration into a file and later create a replica of the same bigIP with that configuration.

[This reference](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K13132#BackingUp) mentioned following this:

**Create the UCS archive file by using the following command syntax, replacing  with the full path to the UCS archive file:**

```
tmsh save /sys ucs <path/to/UCS>
```

I logged in to my bigIP, but when trying this, it gives me error. What is the problem? How to fix it?

```
Syntax Error: "ucs" unexpected argument
```

Comment: what version is your BIG-IP?

Comment: It is 13. But I figured out the problem: I needed to be admin role only!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an `operator` role. I needed to have an `administrator` or `iRule Manager`(or something similar?) role only for this to show up!

Answer (score 3):

(tmos)# save /sys ucs

Configuration Items:

foobar.ucs

I guess you are under tmos shell, right?

I mean you have to enter in tmos shell running the command "tmsh". Then, you have to write the rest of your input

Example:

```
[root@F5-LTM:Active:In Sync] config # tmsh
root@(F5-LTM)(cfg-sync In Sync)(Active)(/Common)(tmos)# save /sys ucs foobar.ucs
```

Comment: Yes this is what I'm doing. But still get `Syntax Error: "ucs" unexpected argument` :-/

Comment: have you tried to tab after each command to see the options you have?

Comment: Interesting. I only have `config` after `sys`, and after that `Options:
  current-partition   partitions`. No `ucs` there.

Comment: is it licensed corretly?